# Azure Pipelines: "No packages matched the search pattern."

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure-devops, nuget, azure-pipelines

I am writing a YAML pipeline that should publish a NuGet package.

When coming to the *deployment job* I get a warning: "No packages matched the search pattern."
The package is there and it is confirmed by the log

```
Downloaded drop/PackageName.1.0.0.nupkg to d:\a\1\drop\PackageName.1.0.0.nupkg
```

and the variable `packagesToPush` is set to `**/*.nupkg;!**/*.symbols.nupkg`.

What am I missing here?

I also tried with different folders like `$(Build.ArtifactgDirectory)/**/*.nupkg;!$(Build.ArtifactDirectory)/**/*.symbols.nupkg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After multiple attempts, this works:

```
'$(Pipeline.Workspace)/**/drop/*.nupkg'
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for sharing your solution here, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) , so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks！

Comment: this was working all the time. suddenly stopped working for me also. did Microsoft change something?

Answer (score 11):

You should use `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` instead of `$(Build.ArtifactgDirectory)`.

```
$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*.nupkg;!$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*.symbols.nupkg
```

Answer (score 2):

you have a typo in ArtifactgDirectory.

Comment: This answer isn't helpful because it doesn't point out the typo.  Also, this question already has a satisfactory answer, so we should leave it alone unless there is something new to add (e.g. based on a new technology that changes the solution).

Comment: He does. Well spotted :)

Answer (score 1):

We are running on Windows agents and had to use backward slashes:

```
$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\**\*.nupkg
```

Answer (score 0):

Today I checked and this is the only one that worked for me:

> $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_ArtifactSourceAlias/drop/*.nupkg

Change _ArtifactSourceAlias with your project name.

Or see the below image to see where to find it. **Source Alias Textbox**
[image]

happy testing!!!

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to you back or forward slashes if you work with a linux vmImage

For me the problem was back slashes (Wrong path: '<path>\<project name>.csproj' for ubuntu-latest)

```yaml
...
      vmImage: ubuntu-latest #Part of the problem

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      inputs:
        command: 'restore'
        projects: '<path>/<project name>.csproj' #Correct! path for ubuntu-latest
...
```